# How to make custom dependency of my project?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

my custom library pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-   core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

tried empty  too, anyway after mvn install I am giving .jar

my gradle where I am trying include this library

`implementation fileTree(dir: 'path to my target', include: ['*.jar'])`

also I tried at project structure add jar like library, also like a module.

All I got was this that I can use my library classes at my project, but InteliJ idea can't find them.

but I can find my classes at project

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You have two local projects, the first is built using Maven, and the second is Gradle. And you want to include the jar file of the first one to the second one as dependency.

Comment: yes, u understand correctly, jar or dependency, at second gradle project i need some classes from maven project

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same configuration in my local and found that the maven application jar has the classes inside BOOT-INF folder, that is why IntelliJ isn't finding them.
The following custom JAR task worked for me

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version> 
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${main-class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After doing a clean install, you will find the custom JAR in the specified output directory, organized according to the original package structure of your application's classes.
Now if you rebuild your gradle project, IntelliJ should be able to find your maven project's classes.
Hope this works for you!